# Facebook app does not work anymore after removing it from app menu in facebook

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

im developing a facebook app that at moment works fine for all tester users , but yesterday one of them removed it from the facebook menu and now the app does not works for him. i Think is a permission problem.
app permissions :
'email',
'user_location',
'read_stream',
'user_birthday',
'user_likes',
'public_profile
The app basically take the user posts and likes of the last year , and then it shows most relevant ones to the user.App developed with facebook PHP sdk.
Any idea? i can provide  more info id needed.

Comment: Describe better what you mean by "removed it from the facebook menu." **What** Facebook menu?

Comment: I meant the list in which you can find all the apps you grant permissions.
this : https://www.facebook.com/settings?tab=applications

Comment: Aha! See my answer below, then.

Answer (score 1):

When someone removes an app from their list of approved Facebook apps, it will stop working for them. That's the whole purpose of managing that list. All permissions are removed. They can authorize the app again, but until they do, it cannot get to their account.

The person could've also blocked your app by accident when doing this, as that's an option. If that's the case, they'll never see your app again. They'll have to go to their blocked apps area (under Security from anywhere on a Facebook web page) and unblock your app before they can reauthorize the app. If the app is not blocked, though, but not authorized, what you describe can still happen.

Comment: App is not blocked for him (he cant see it in the blocked app list).
But he can see it in the app list (with all the other apps)

Comment: Then he **didn't** remove the app, as you said earlier. I can't help with conflicting information.

Comment: He removed it 100% sure, because i was next to him. then we tried to access again. tnx for the help anyway.

Comment: Well, does "the app list" mean the list of **approved** apps, or **available** apps? If the former, then he did **not** remove it. If the latter, then he **did** remove it, and what I described in the first sentence still applies: removing an app from the list of approved apps denies the app permission to access the account, even if it's not blocked. I'll clarify the answer with this in mind.